# get_model equivalent for ModelForms?

Tags: django, modelform

I have a multiple ModelForm classes that each represent a different Model. I would like to have a generic 'create' function that loads the specified model form based on a URL parameter. It is possible to load a model dynamically with this:

```
model_name = 'TestModel'
m = get_model('AppLabel', model_name)
```

Does anyone know how I can achieve the same for ModelForms, something like:

```
modelform_name = 'TestModelForm'
f = get_form('AppLabel', modelform_name)
if f.is_valid():
    ...
```

I can not think of a way to do this with generic views - they require the ModelForm to be passed, rather than just its name. If I get the model with get_model then pass that to the generic view it will display a form but I am unable to exclude model fields.

TIA for any tips

Comment: alternatively have a custom view handling your urls & inside the custom view get the form_class and then call the generic view with the form _class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a `ModelForm` it does not register itself with its model's app. (Based on experience and a quick browse through the source).

Here are some otheroptions I can think of:

1. **All `ModelForm` classes exist in a single module:** Use `getattr` on that module based on the string.
2. **`ModelForm`'s are spread out among many models and you have a reasonable (<30) amount of forms:**
   Create a dictionary mapping from form strings you expect to ModelForm classes. For example:

   ```
   from some_app.forms import FirstModelForm
   from another_app.forms import SecondModelForm
   from additional_app.forms import FirstModelForm as AdditionalAppFirstModelForm # Will allow for managing conflicting names easily.

   form_mapping = {
       'FirstModelForm': FirstModelForm,
       'SecondModelForm': SecondForm,
       'AdditionalAppFirstModelForm': AdditionalAppFirstModelForm,
   }

   request_form_class = request.POST.get('form_class')
   f = form_mapping.get(request_form_class)(request.POST)

   if f.is_valid():
       f.save()
   ```
3. **You're dealing with a lot of forms**: Create a baseclass for your ModelForm, or replace the `BaseModelFormMetaclass` at runtime.  You'll have to deal with issues such as name conflicts, duplicate `ModelForm`s for the same `Model` "automagically", so prepare for some headaches.  It would be pretty rad if you could pull it off.

Personally (as you can probably see), I'd just go with option #2.

Comment: @Mike: You're very welcome. Remember from the "Zen of Python" (`import this`): "Explicit is better than implicit.".  The #3 would be a require way to much "voodoo" to be considered close to explicit.  Also, be sure to add some error checking when you get the form class and raise the appropriate `Http404`.  It'll save you some headaches in the future.

Answer (score -1):

An alternate method for this is to replace `forms.py` with a package called `forms`. Then, in `__init__.py` within that package, import all your `ModelForm`s.

Then you can use sdolan's Option #1.

Comment: This answer does not address the question. The question was how to dynamically load a particular form class, given a model name.

Comment: Also, the question was successfully answered five years ago.